# Auto load all link on one pages

Tags: javascript

I want to make a list of links in a page and when we open the page, it will automatically open/load the links in sequence by a certain time delay.

Is this possible with JavaScript? I'm not so knowledgeable, I hope someone help me thanks.

Comment: Once link is "clicked", the browser navigate to different location so you pretty much lose control over it. You mean open the links as pop up windows, each in its own window?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. You have to iterate over all elements of the document. If element is link, do what you want. You can use AJAX.

But I do not really understand how will you "load the link". What will you do with it? Store in memory? But what will happen when user clicks the link?

Comment: I mean,,, I have created a link on the page will automatically open when the page is accessed

for example:
I make a list of links and then I save it in notepad as html files.
When I open the html file, then link that I have made the list will automatically open in sequence within a certain delay.
Actually the link was not referring to a page, but a json code to inject and make something becomes available.
This example links:
http://www.blabla.com/chat/gsi/index.php?X=1305015082484&amp;v=json&amp;m=%5B%5B6842%2C%5B%22%7B%7D%2​2%2C%221704025937%22%2C%221309857057%22%5D%5D%5D

Comment: I'll make a link that differ in sequence only one number on 1309857057 then 1309857058 and so on

Answer (score 0):

Possible, with such pure JavaScript code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    var links = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        curHref = anchors[i].href;
        if (curHref.length > 0)
            links.push(curHref);
    }
    OpenLink(links, 0);
};

function OpenLink(links, index) {
    if (index >= links.length)
        return false;
    window.open(links[index], "_blank");
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        OpenLink(links, index + 1);
    }, 1000);
}
```

This will iterate over all the links and open each as pop up window - modern browsers will block this by default so user will have to enable pop up windows for your website.

If you mean something else, please edit your question and clarify.

Live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/w5tdv/